# Determinant of $2 \times 2$ block matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

How to find the determinant of the following block matrix?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & A \\ 
A & kI
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here, $A$ is any square matrix, $I$ is an identity matrix and $k$ is any constant.

Comment: I do not know about your answer

Comment: Hint: Use row operations to transform the matrix into $\begin{bmatrix}A&A\\0&kI-A\end{bmatrix}$.  Then, some formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & A \\ 
A & kI
\end{bmatrix}$$

is equivalent to the following block matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & A \\ 
0 & kI-A
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is now a block triangular matrix with determinant

$$\det(A) \det(kI-A)$$

Answer (score 1):

Or write your matrix like this
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & A
\\
A & kI \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \frac{1}{k}A
\\
A-kI & I \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
I & 0
\\
kI & kI \end{array}\right)$$
Then properties of determinants give
$$\det\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & A
\\
A & kI \end{array}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{k}\det(A-kI)\det(A)k=\det(A-kI)\det(A)$$